# Distinct on two columns with same data type

Tags: laravel, eloquent, distinct

In my game application I have a `combats` table:

```
  id   player_one_id   player_two_id  
 ---- --------------- --------------- 
   1               1               2  
   2               1               3  
   3               3               4  
   4               4               1
```

Now I need to know hoy many unique users played the game. How can I apply distinct, count on both columns `player_one_id` and `player_two_id`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using union you can get unique distinct value.

```
$playerone = DB::table("combats")
    ->select("combats.player_one_id");

$playertwo = DB::table("combats")
    ->select("combats.player_two_id")
    ->union($playerone)
    ->count();
```